# Converting nested JSON object to pandas Dataframe

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe, nested-json

I am dealing with a JSON file which has nested fields (arrays). I am trying to convert the same into a Pandas dataframe.

```
{
    "_id": "2026",
    "dataDate": 1537920000000,
    "dataYear": 2018,
    "groupId": "1378",
    "HourConsumed": 19781.4,
    "HourGenerated": 0,
    "max": 4658.400000000001,
    "maxGen": 0,
    "maxTime": 1538001000000,
    "avg": -206.05625,
    "max": 0,
    "maxGen": 0,
    "maxTime": null,
    "avgTemp": 0,
    "me_Id": "2004506_3166155129",
    "interval": 15,
    "intervalMetaData": [
        "whC",
        "whG",
        "max",
        "maxGen",
        "hC",
        "hG",
        "maxVar",
        "maxGen",
        "avgTemp",
        "eventTime"
    ],
    "intervalData": [
        [
            175.2,
            0,
            700.8,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1537920900000
        ],
        [
            192,
            0,
            768,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1537921800000
        ],
        [
            191.39999999999998,
            0,
            765.5999999999999,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1537922700000
        ]
    ]
}
```

I need to create separate columns of what's inside `intervalMetaData`, and then filling those columns with values from `intervalData`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just have to set your columns right by importing your list of lists with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "_id": "2026",
    "dataDate": 1537920000000,
    "dataYear": 2018,
    "groupId": "1378",
    "HourConsumed": 19781.4,
    "HourGenerated": 0,
    "max": 4658.400000000001,
    "maxGen": 0,
    "maxTime": 1538001000000,
    "avg": -206.05625,
    "max": 0,
    "maxGen": 0,
    "maxTime": None,
    "avgTemp": 0,
    "me_Id": "2004506_3166155129",
    "interval": 15,
    "intervalMetaData": [
        "whC",
        "whG",
        "max",
        "maxGen",
        "hC",
        "hG",
        "maxVar",
        "maxGen",
        "avgTemp",
        "eventTime"
    ],
    "intervalData": [
        [
            175.2,
            0,
            700.8,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1537920900000
        ],
        [
            192,
            0,
            768,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1537921800000
        ],
        [
            191.39999999999998,
            0,
            765.5999999999999,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1537922700000
        ]
    ]
}


df = pd.DataFrame(data["intervalData"], columns=data["intervalMetaData"])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     whC  whG    max  maxGen  hC  hG  maxVar  maxGen  avgTemp      eventTime
0  175.2    0  700.8       0   0   0       0       0        0  1537920900000
1  192.0    0  768.0       0   0   0       0       0        0  1537921800000
2  191.4    0  765.6       0   0   0       0       0        0  1537922700000
```

Edit: you can add the other keys as columns with a loop:

```
for k,v in data.items():
    if k not in ["intervalData", "intervalMetaData"]:
        df[k] = v
```

Comment: That's great. Would it be possible to get the other fields as well in the same dataframe? It might be repeated I understand but that's not a problem

Comment: sure! I added a loop to my answer

Answer (score 1):

You bet it's possible! It's as simple as this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(j['intervalData'], columns=j['intervalMetaData'])
```

Comment: @shivanshu does this not solve your problem?